# Add a class to UL of links.phtml lists in Magento

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, magento, magento-1.7

I want to be able to add a class to the UL element of lists that are output using the block `type="page/template_links"` that uses the template page/template/links.phtml (eg: top links, footer links).

Is there a way to add a class via the XML? An attribute on `<block />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by making a slight modification to `page/template/links.phtml` and subsequently creating a small piece of layout xml for each links block you wish to add a class to.

First, if you haven't already done so, copy over `page/template/links.phtml` to you theme and add the following inside the class attribute of the ul tag:

```
<?php echo $this->getClass() ?>
```

Then, taking the footer links block as an example, the layout snippet would look like this (obviously replacing 'test-class' with the class you wish to apply to the ul):

```
<reference name="footer_links">
    <action method="setClass"><class>test-class</class></action>
</reference>
```